# After long pause in app Spring Kafka stops consuming messages

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Running Kafka and Spring Boot locally, sending and consumer messages via Spring Cloud Stream. In my consumer app, when I put a break point during the processing of a message for a particular topic, and keep all threads paused for around 30 minutes, then resume the app. The app stops processing messages.

The error I see in the app logs is the following, and this error is repeated for each topic for at least 30 minutes, until finally the app resumes consuming messages.

```
24-08-2022 20:04:17.873 ERROR [KafkaConsumerDestination{consumerDestinationName='my-test-topic', partitions=1, dlqName='null'}.container-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.error - Consumer exception 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'java.lang.IllegalStateException's; no record information is available
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:151)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:113)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1439)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1136)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can only check the position for partitions assigned to this consumer.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.position(KafkaConsumer.java:1742)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.position(KafkaConsumer.java:1709)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor185.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy263.position(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.seekPartitions(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.checkIdle(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1087)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

I retrieved the following runtime settings from the debugger in `org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.ListenerConsumer#pollAndInvoke`:

```
KafkaMessageListenerContainer.ListenerConsumer [containerProperties=ContainerProperties [topics=[my-test-topic], pollTimeout=5000, consumerRebalanceListener=org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer$1@3008d5e7, syncCommits=true, syncCommitTimeout=PT1M, authorizationExceptionRetryInterval=null, ackMode=BATCH, ackCount=1, ackTime=5000, messageListener=org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter@61ad1464, consumerTaskExecutor=org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor@1f7727c, shutdownTimeout=10000, ackOnError=false, idleEventInterval=30000, monitorInterval=30, noPollThreshold=3.0, subBatchPerPartition=null, assignmentCommitOption=LATEST_ONLY_NO_TX, deliveryAttemptHeader=false, eosMode=BETA], listenerType=ACKNOWLEDGING_CONSUMER_AWARE, isConsumerAwareListener=true, isBatchListener=false, autoCommit=false, consumerGroupId=mygroup, clientIdSuffix=-0]
```

I also have the following consumer properties set:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumerProperties.metadata.max.age.ms=300000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumerProperties.max.poll.interval.ms=60000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumerProperties.session.timeout.ms=45000
```

These are my versions for the consumer app:

```
+- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:jar:5.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.1.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:5.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jmx:jar:5.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-context:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- net.jodah:typetools:jar:0.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-core:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.4.5-6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.6.9:compile
```

I've noticed this happening before while debugging and the only way to resolve it immediately (other than wait up to an hour) is to restart the kafka brokers and/or the app. Would like to have this resolve itself more quickly.

Comment: This is expected behaviour. The consumer group will rebalance after a few seconds if there is no heartbeat, or seems you overwrote related properties to about 1 minute

Comment: It seems though that once the app resumes, it's unable to get the reassigned partitions until around 40 minutes, but keeps trying to read from the previously assigned partitions that were reassigned, judging from the error messages. Shouldn't it detect this failure and attempt to recover sooner? Also not sure what setting controls this period.

Comment: After a rebalance from other consumers in the group stopping, or after `metadata.max.age.ms` the client re-requests topic information